# JFrame graphics stuttering on Linux

Tags: java, linux, swing, jframe, frame-rate

I am writing a simple game of Tetris in Java (it's been years since I've touched Java); however I am developing on Linux, and for the first time ever this game is refreshing very irregularly. I've written almost nothing but the refresh-rate is stuttering until I hover my cursor over the window and maintain constant movement within the window (simply clicking on or hovering over the window does not affect the framerate). Given this, I am led to believe that it is some sort of event issue in my code, but it is written just as I've written games in Java before.

Main class:

```
public class GameWin
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Engine TEngine = new Engine();

        JFrame Win = new JFrame("Tetris Window");
            Win.setSize(224,384+17);
            Win.setDefaultCloseOperation(Win.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Win.setVisible(true);
            Win.setResizable(false);
            Win.add(TEngine);
    }
}
```

Engine code:

```
public class Engine extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    public Timer thread = new Timer(30, this);
    Graphics g;
    int x = 0;

    public Engine()
    {
        thread.start();
    }

    public void update()
    {
        x++;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        super.paintComponent(g2d);
        this.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
        g2d.setColor(new Color(0,0,0));

        g2d.drawRect(32,32,160,320);
        g2d.fillRect(34+x%100,34+x%100,14,14);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        update();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

This isn't a personal project, but I'm doing it for a grade. I've tried other solutions here on Stack Overflow but they haven't helped my situation. Would any of you have insight? Any and all responses are appreciated.

Comment: Creating new objects in your paint function is not a good idea.  Use `Color.WHITE` and `Color.BLACK` instead of `new Color(255,255,255)` and `new Color(0,0,0)`.  This likely isn't your entire problem, but will be a step in the right direction.  Additionally, you only need to set the background colour once, such as in the constructor.  You can then remove the `setBackground()` call from the `paintComponent` as well.

Comment: ah thanks, much appreciated

Comment: If you included your imports it might be easier for people to try and recreate your issue and have a play around.

Comment: Calling `Win.setVisible` before `Win.add` is a mistake which could result in the panel not been displayed (or displayed when you expect it to be).  You could consider reducing the delay from `30` to something like `5`

Comment: The `RepaintManager` could also be consolidating paint requests, reducing your updates to a minimal set (so `x` is been updated `n` times, but the component is getting painted less times). The same thing could be happening to the `Timer`.  If the `Timer` events still exist in the Event Queue, the `Timer` may consolidate them instead of posting new events on the Event Queue, while you can configure the `Timer`, overcoming the issues with the `RepaintManager` are far more complicated